# How to receive and print location in PHP

Tags: php, web, printing, location

I would like to know how to get the location of a computer that goes on a website like Google maps and it asks if you if it can get your location but in PHP and then prints it on a webpage.

Comment: Welcome to SO :) You're not likely to get any help with this. You need to do some research, try something, then if you run into trouble, post your attempt, what you're trying to do, and what is not working. For more see [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: Ive posted an answer but agree with the above comments. I think a little more research would go a long way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could attempt find the location by running a php executed shell command of  tracerout on  the $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] but there are many factors which make that method very unreliable.

If you need the location of the computer executing your application.  I recommend using HTML5 geolocation http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp
and passing the data back to the server via AJAX or some other posting method like a form.

Comment: thanks so much it was so helpfull